# How to plot a message bool in a bag file?

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A lot of times there's a bool in a message which qualifies analog data in the message; e.g. nav_data_valid or is_stopped, and which needs to be viewed to understand node behavior. I know I can look at these values in rqt_bag by viewing the raw message, but that doesn't readily show 1-cycle blips in these booleans, or put them in the context of related variables like speed. rqt_bag and bag-tools/plot.py don't allow plotting bools.

I have to imagine this is a common use case - how do people handle it? Thanks for any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323001/how-to-plot-a-message-bool-in-a-bag-file?/) by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 300 on 2019-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found that bag-tools/plot.py does actually plot bools as value 0 or 1 for False or True.

---

Originally posted by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) with karma: 300 on 2019-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0